# Answers with equal votes but one is accepted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, accepted-answer, sorting

OK I think a feature has been added recently to SO (and probably other SE sites) that answers are by default sorted according the votes, regardless of the accepted answer, so the accepted one could be the second if there's an answer that has higher number of votes (sum).

However, answers with equal votes are usually just sorted in an arbitrary order, there is no rules for that.

The (possible) bug I want to report is this:

[image]

As you can see, there's two answers with equal number of votes, so usually they're sorted in an arbitrary order. However, one of them is the accepted answer, shouldn't it **always** be at the top?

Note that if you refresh the page, the arbitrary order may place the accepted answer at the top, but might also place it not at the top (as shown in the picture).

I don't know if you really consider it a mistake, or you are aware of it and just like it this way.

This is the question in which I discovered the problem: [Rails 3 - Restricting formats for action in resource routes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997788/368167) (of course votes will change in time).